# jQuery: Unable to set values of cloned input element and cannot copy disabled property

Tags: html, jquery

I'm having issues setting up new values to cloned input fields.

```
clonedElement = element.clone(true); //This is a whole DIV which has inputs in it.
```

I then search for the inputs and modify as needed.

```
var newValue = "New Value";
$(clonedElement).find("#"+id).val(newValue);
```

every time I try to set a value (before appending the clonedElement) I get the following error.

```
Uncaught DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
```

however, this works using the same process.

```
$(clonedElement).find("#"+id).val("");
```

Also, changing values to attributes such as the name also work as expected

```
vew newName = "new_name";
$(clonedElement).find("#"+id).attr("name", newName);
```

I can set a blank value and empty the fields but I cannot pass any actual values, neither coming from another variable or even hard-coded values, only blank works.

Another thing I noticed is that the **"disabled" property** is not getting copied along with the cloned inputs. All other attributes and properties do get copied.

Any ideas how to get new values added to cloned elements before appending the element to the document?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. You should use classes, not IDs.

Comment: you are right and I get that. I cloned the parent container found each input and modified the IDs with a unique index value appended to each ID, changed the field name (literally made each field identifier unique and THEN tried to update the field value and still doesn't work. I no longer get the Uncaught DOMException error but the values do not get updated.

Comment: Are you using Firefox? I googled that error message and it seems to be something related to trying to use an element in certain ways before it has been added to the DOM. So try appending it first, then set the value.

Comment: Yes, firefox and I tried that before but the issue was with something else and it was related to an file type input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what the problem was. there is an **input type file** among all of the inputs and since I was looping all inputs to set the value without filtering some input types, the loop broke whenever it reached a select.

To fix the issue i simple did something like this.

```
var newValue = "my new value";
$("#"+newId+":not(input[type=file])", clonedElement).val(newValue);

$("#"+newId+":input[type=file]", clonedElement).text(newValue);
```

that's a workaround that worked for me and can easily be improved.